# how to write an array in stl in c++

Tags: c++

how does one write an `array` in `stl` inside a class? i want to write an `array in stl` and overload the operators
`()[]` in c++ i know how to overload operators but i have no idea on how stl works...
i can overload operators `()[]` like this below i have used matrix as an example here to show on how i can overload the operators

```
int* operator[] (int i) {
        if (i < 10) 
        {
            return matrix[i];
        }

    }

    int* operator() (int i) {
        if (i < 10) 
        {
            return matrix[i];
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in STL"?

Comment: What is an _array in stl_ ??

Comment: It's is not clear at all what you're asking. The standard template library has a bunch of containers. You can't "write an array in STL", the STL is not something you can modify.

Comment: What do you mean by "an array in stl"? To me, STL stands for Standard Template Library or Stephan T. Lavavej.

Comment: Here's an list of containers and their methods http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write an array useful in the STL context you'd have a look at the container requirements and implement the corresponding functions. In particular, to make the sequence accessible to STL algorithms you'd implement `begin()` and `end()` methods providing access to the content. Depending on whether you want to have a fixed sized array or a variable sized array have a look at `std::array<T, N>` or `std::vector<T>` for an idea of a reasonable interface.

Comment: Arrays are _useful in the STL context_ by your definition just by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to see how a templatized array implementation works, take a look at Boost's [`array.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/array.hpp).